# Ruler and Compass in the Hyperbolic Plane

Tags: ring-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I've been studying Ring Theory, and there is a marvellous chapter about Constructible Numbers and Euclidean Geometry (LEQUAIN, Y et al. Elementos de Álgebra) and I began wondering: What about the Hyperbolic Geometry?

I studied the Hyperbolic Plane in three ways: Without models, Half-Plane Poincaré Model and Disk Poincaré Model.
But I'm not sure about this question: What are the analogue in the hyperbolic plane for euclidean non-graduated ruler and compass that can make the Constructible Numbers?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A length $t$ in the hyperbolic plane can be constructed if and only if $\sinh t$ is a length that can be constructed in the Euclidean plane. The constructible angles in the hyperbolic plane are exactly the same as those in the Euclidean plane.

[My Article](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf)

[Place to download Marvin's article](http://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/old-and-new-results-in-the-foundations-of-elementary-plane-euclidean-and-non-euclidean-geometries)  click on Read The Article in blue letters

Comment: thanks! i'm gonna try to prove the equivalence you said.

Comment: It is also described and explained in "Introduction to Hyperbolic geometry " by  Ramsay and Richtmeyer ISBN 0-387-94339-0 pages 255 - 275,page 259 says a length $y$ can be constructed if $ e^{-y} $ is in a quadratic-surd field. I think the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @Willemien yes, they are the same. In his book, Hartshorne goes so far as to make a "multiplicative" length, which would be the same as $e^x$  for length $x$ in the ordinary hyperbolic plane. The length of two consecutive line segments in a line becomes the product, the length of a single point is $1,$ and so on. This way he avoids any transcendental functions or limiting processes.

Comment: I wonder if a tool for drawing equidistants would be permissible for the constructions? Technically, it would be a simple device -- a ruler you move along the line, with a perpendicular arm where you can set a pencil at a certain distance to draw an equidistant when the ruler moves.

Comment: @Marek14 that is actually how Mordukhai-Boltovskoi originally proved the result, maybe about 1930. Later, Nesterovich showed that the extra instruments did not change the set of points that could be constructed. I give a very brief discussion in my article. I don't think any of this has been translated. i had a Russian friend confirm the contents of one Nesterovich article from about 1949.